# Generic array type for char() and string()

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I am learning about sorting algorithms in school and we are supposed to sort all chars and then implement word sorting.

I used a Char() array and I got word sorting to work with a String() array. Now I would like to combine both into one function:

```
For j = 0 To arr.Length
   For i = 0 To hi
       If arr(i) > arr(i + 1) Then
           Swap(arr, i, i + 1)
       End If
   Next
   hi -= 1
Next
```

How can I make it so that arr can be both Char() and String()?

I tried:

```
If bolWords Then
    Dim arr As String()
Else
    Dim arr As Char()
End If
```

But it says it's undeclared because of the scope. I also tried Object(), but when I do ToCharArray() it says something is wrong about the referencetype.

Could I maybe use a Char() array for sorting words too?

Comment: Can't you just use `String()` for both? A `String` variable can contain a `Char`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the Array type as an argument and could send your arrays to the somewhat more generic method.

In the method, I check whether the item implements IComparable, and if it does, use the IComparable implementation. If not, simply use the <> algorithm.

The show method then also shows the arrays:

```
Sub Sort(ByRef items As Array)
    For i As Integer = LBound(items) To UBound(items)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(items)
            If (items(i).GetType() Is GetType(IComparable) AndAlso items(i).CompareTo(items(j)) > 0) OrElse items(i) > items(j) Then
                Dim copy = items(j)
                items(j) = items(i)
                items(i) = copy
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Sub Show(strTitle As String, items As Array)
    Console.WriteLine(strTitle + vbCrLf + New String("-", strTitle.Length))
    For Each item In items
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", item)
    Next
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim strArray() As String = {"Test", "Abc", "Copy", "Sorter", "Bubble"}
    Dim chrArray() As Char = {"a", "b", "q", "m", "j", "z", "c", "0"}
    Dim intArray() As Integer = {5, 3, 7, 9, 10, 5464, 4, 1, 3, 3}

    Sort(strArray)
    Sort(chrArray)
    Sort(intArray)

    Show("Sorted strings", strArray)
    Show("Sorted chars", chrArray)
    Show("Sorted ints", intArray)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with generics and a lambda like so:

```
Sub SortArray(Of T)(arr As T(), isGreater As Func(Of T, T, Boolean))
    For j = 0 To arr.Length
        For i = 0 To arr.Length - 2
            If isGreater(arr(i), arr(i + 1)) Then
                Dim tmp = arr(i)
                arr(i) = arr(i + 1)
                arr(i + 1) = tmp
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Dim xs = { "D", "B", "C", "E", "F", "A" }

SortArray(xs, Function (x1, x2) x1 > x2)
```

With this approach you can sort any type of array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner:

```vb
Public Function Sort(Of T)(ByVal Items As IEnumerable(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Return Items.OrderBy(Function(i) i)
End Function
```

And then you'd call it like this:

```vb
Dim arr() As String = { ... } ' could be a string or a character array
arr = Sort(arr).ToArray()
```

But since the real goal here is to learn about generics and basic sorting algorithms, I can point out some things you need to do with your existing code for it to work:

First up is this line:

```vb
If arr(i) > arr(i + 1) Then
```

The problem is the `>` comparison. For any two random types, you can't know for sure that the `>` operator is defined. Instead, you need to write it like this:

```vb
If arr(i).CompareTo(arr(i + 1)) > 0 Then
```

Additionally, for this work, you need to declare your sort method so that you constrain it to the IComparable interface, like this:

```vb
Public Sub Sort(Of T As IComparable)(ByVal arr() As T)
```

If you do that, then the rest of your original code should work without further changes.

Comment: does Char implement IComparable? According to compiler it didn't